# html5 - Table Footers in the middle of a table -- is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, html, datatable

I'm working in html5/asp.net 2012 and creating a table that contains the standard thead, tbody, and tfoot tags.  The table will contain multiple schools, and ideally I'd like to have a summary footer after each school, like so:

Header Row

School Detail

School Detail

Footer Row

School Detail

School Detail

Footer Row

I know in previous versions of html this was not possible, but thought it was in html5.  However, when I run the code I get the standard "headers/body/footers must be in exact order" message.  Is there a trick or workaround that I can do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [`tfoot`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element) can only appear in a table **once**, and must be before any `tbody` or `tr` elements, and after any `thead` element (I've glossed over some other elements there, see the link for details).

To get the effect you're talking about, you might use multiple `tbody` elements, even though semantically of course that's incorrect.

Alternately, you could use multiple tables (nested or just one after the other).

Comment: I thought about nested tables after I posted this, but I think I may try the multiple tbody elements first...thanks for the confirmation and suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tfoot must be above the tbody. A little annoying I know but that's the standard.

However one way around your problem is to use multiple tbody's which is 100% valid. To help separate this you can attach a different class to each tbody so you can style it differently.

So you could do something like:

---

thead

tbody.normal

tbody.footer

tbody.normal

tbody.footer

tbody.normal

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation...I hadn't thought about breaking it out into individual classes...but yeah I don't see why that wouldn't work!!  Thanks for the suggestion!